# Adding Tree list in list box in catia vba

Tags: vba, catia

I'm trying to add tree items in a list box in Catia. I tried with this code. But it's showing an error.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  For N = 1 To CATIA.Document.Count

    Set Dokument = CATIA.Document.Item(N)

    For i = 2 To Dokument.Product.Products.Count

      Set InstDokument = Dokument.Product.Products.Item(i)

      UserForm15.ListBox11234.AddItem InstDokument.Name

    Next

  Next

End Sub
```

> Error: Run time error '438':
> Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: In which you get an error? Which object doesn't support this property (use watch/locals window)? Be aware the documents-collection also includes all document which may not have a products collection (drawings, parts, ...)

Comment: There is a typo: its .Document**s**

Comment: it is not showing error in particular line. it just displaying small window and saying Error: Run time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. and i corrected the typo but still not working. if i open new catia and run this code is working fine for first time. if i run it again it shows error

Comment: If it is not possible to correct the above code. please suggest your won code for how to add tree list in list box in Catia active document.

Comment: Is there a debug button on this error window? Have you tried to set a breakpoint and run the code step wise?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72552142/catvba-catia-recursive-loop-throught-product-tree/72552424#72552424) shows you how get the complete tree of a opened CatProduct